# calling web method and post back method on same button

Tags: jquery, .net, web-services, http

I have a button like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-small" id="attendYes" data-rsvp="2" runat="server">Yes</button>
```

This was originally calling a web method via jQuery to commit data to the database, and then on success callback the button colour was changed. I then added a post back event for this button in order to serve an ICAL file to the user.

As soon as I called the postback method I started getting a failure from the ajax call. The web service runs correctly, and I can see in fiddler it has returned the correct JSON object, although fiddler shows the icon "Session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server."

The database is changed and the ICAL file is served, my issue is the fail callback always runs, even before the web method has finished. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: How do you call the postback?

Comment: Just with the standard postback javascript .net adds for runat controls bound to an event, I don't specifically call it.

Comment: Then it is normal that your ajax call fails. A postback is actually a redirect to the browser. Whenever a browser starts a post back it stops all current ajax calls as they are no longer needed to be executed when the browser changes the html content either way. You would have to wait until your ajax is completed and then call the post back. But that makes no sense in my opinion

Comment: Agreed, Ideally I would do it all in the one web method but I cannot use the response stream to serve a file during a web method call. I figured I may have to call it manually on the success of the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your help - if you'd like to make an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is completely normal.

A postback is like a redirect for the browser. Which means the whole HTML document gets unloaded, and a new document is requested from the server.

Therefor the browser stops all Javascript / AJAX that is currently running as the browser unloads the whole document either way. The browser sends a cancel request for all currently pending ajax requests to the corresponding servers, resulting in errors.

You would have to wait for the ajax call to finish and then do the post back.